# Running Sub Workbook_BeforePrint when only printing the active sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am only wanting to be printing one sheet at a time (due to have a huge amount of data that would result in 1000 pages if I was printing the whole workbook) but I want the header to automatically update before I print.  The header will have a formula that refers to cells and inserts that cell's value. However, Worksheet_BeforePrint does not seem to be a thing, and Workbook_BeforePrint doesn't work if only printing the active sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rptdate As String

Dim ride As String
Dim sht As String
sht = ActiveSheet.Name
rptdate = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B3").Value
prov = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B4").Value
ride = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B5").Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = sht  & " Ride Name: " & ride & " First Report Date: " & rpdate

End Sub
```

I am wanting the header to show something like: 
"Sheet Name
Ride Name: ride
First Report Date: rptdate"
Preferably on 3 lines like indicated above. 
The above code works if I am to print the whole workbook, but not when I only want to print the Active Worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really printed from VBA before, but you may be able to use the `PrintOut` method from the worksheet object. So act as if you are printing the workbook to trigger the `Workbook_BeforePrint` event. Don't worry, you will cancel this print job.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim rptdate As String, ride As String, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    rptdate = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B3").Value
    ride = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B5").Value
    ws.PageSetup.RightHeader = ws.Name & " Ride Name: " & ride & " First Report Date: " & rpdate
    ws.PrintOut

    ' Cancel the entire workbook printjob - it's as simple as changing this boolean value
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Setting `Cancel = True` will cancel the entire workbook print, and `ws.PrintOut` will print only your active worksheet.

And my apologies, I am not currently in an environment where I can test this at the moment.